# how can I catch promise error if doesnt exist any value?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

When the user enters a promotional code, this may exist or not. I'm returning the error in this way, but it seems as if the server crushes and it returns many lines of error. 
How can I optimize the code to make it cleaner? Is this form correct? I do not control much of node and JS and it's hard to see which is the best way...

Here is my code in the controller:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Promotion = mongoose.model('Promotion'),
    q = require('q'),
    Promise = q.Promise;

var PromotionController = {

    applyPromo: function(promoCode) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            if(promoCode === null) {
                resolve(false);
            }

            Promotion.find({code: promoCode}, function (err, elements) {

                if (err)
                {
                    reject(err);
                }

                if((elements !== null) && (elements.length > 0)) {
                    console.log('OK');
                    console.log(elements[0]);
                    resolve(elements[0]._id);
                }
                else {
                    //reject(new Error('Doesnt exist ' + promoCode));
                }
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = PromotionController;
```

And my server shows:

```
Error: Doesnt exist codeExample
    at /home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/api/controllers/promotions.js:36:13
    at /home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4599:16
    at /home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4122:12
    at cb (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1777:14)
    at result (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:414:17)
    at executeCallback (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:406:9)
    at handleCallback (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at cursor.close (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:224:62)
    at handleCallback (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at completeClose (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:893:14)
    at Cursor.close (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:912:10)
    at cursor._next (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/cursor_ops.js:224:23)
    at handleCallback (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:204:5)
    at _setCursorNotifiedImpl (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:433:38)
    at self._endSession (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:441:46)
    at Cursor._endSession (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:195:5)
    at Cursor._endSession (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:226:59)
    at _setCursorNotifiedImpl (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:441:17)
    at setCursorNotified (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:433:3)
    at done (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:648:16)
    at queryCallback (/home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:699:18)
    at /home/user/Documentos/myApi/myServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:532:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Comment: `it seems as if the server crushes and it returns many lines of error` What exactly is the error?

Comment: Sorry, forget to add the error lines. I already edited it, thanks!

Comment: It looks like the consumer of `PromotionController` doesn't properly handle the rejected Promise, maybe? Is that an unhandled Promise rejection?

Comment: If I think that's the case, but how can I handle the rejected promise? I'm starting in JS6 and it's complicated for me

Comment: Can you paste the code, how you are calling/handling the error from PromotionController.applyPromo?